# Help in identifying Fuji Suncrest bike based on serial number

Tags: mountain-bike

I got an old Fuji Suncrest Mountain bike that has a serial number F1106059.  Is it possible to deduce the year of manufacturing based on this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps.    However, that model name was produced in years:

- 1994-1996 (steel frames)
- 1999-2000 (aluminium frames)
- 2003-2004 (aluminium frames)

according to: http://bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=1995&brand=Fuji&model=Suncrest

So if you compare the components to the specifications for each year, you might find a match.... this assumes that its running original components still, or that you can pick out and ignore the obviously changed parts.

Answer (score 1):

I know the suncrest started around 1983, because I have that model, with receipt.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycle SE. Please add several photos of the bike you are claiming to have since the year you noted conflicts with the other answer.  Pictures would GREATLY bolster your your claim.